# Can I get the referrer?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-agent, referrer

I have a website on which I dynamically create Javascript code using ASP.NET handler in which I should add the referrer to a database.

I want to get referrer of referrer like so:

- `website1`
- `website2` (where I create pixel to another site)
- `website3` (where pixel is located)

I don't have code access to `website1`, on `website2` I can only assign JavaScript.

If I get referrer in current application state I get `website2`.

Is there a way to get `website1` as referrer?

Comment: *"where i create pixel to another site"* Huh?

Comment: @TJCrowder: pretty sure that is about 1x1 px images which use a referal (query string) to count visitors

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can pass this value along: `document.referrer`.

That expression would need to be evaluated on website 2, not on website 3.

So:

```
// website2.html
<img src="website3.com/pxl.gif" id="pxl" />
<script>
document.getElementById('pxl').src += '?ref=' + encodeURIComponent(document.referrer);
</script>
```

The request to website3 will then include the referrer.

Answer (score 21):

It is impossible to get the referrer of website2 on website3 directly. However, since you can use javascript on website2, you could get the referrer (`document.referrer`) and add it to the url of the pixel you get. For example:

```
var referer = document.referrer;
var pixelUrl = 'http://website3/pixel?referrer=' + escape(referrer);
// create pixel...
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 7):

Seems that `document.referrer` doesn't work in many instances.

Use the complete `window.frames.top.document.referrer` instead.