# how to control window.onload in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making web pages using JavaScript. I have two pages, one is `index` page and `about us` page. there are several links in `index` page that direct to `about us` page, but I want to `window.onload` function different on `about us` page when click different link on `index` page. how to control this?

Below is my codes. when click `About us` link on `index` page, open `about us` page and execute `window.contantChange('1');`
when click `Privacy Policy` link on `index` page, open `about us` page and execute

```
window.contantChange('2')
```

On the `index` page links are

```
 <td class="footerTd"><a href="About-Us/About-Us.html">About Us</a></td>
  <td class="footerTd"><a href="About-Us/About-Us.html">Privacy Policy</a></td>
```

On the About Us page

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        window.contantChange('1');
             function contantChange(ID)
        {
                                var ServicesleftBannerItem = document.getElementsByClassName("ServicesleftBannerItem");
                var ServicesleftBannerItema = document.getElementsByClassName("ServicesleftBannerItema");
                var linkArrow = document.getElementsByClassName("linkArrow");

            for (var i = 0; i < ServicesleftBannerItem.length; i++) 
              {
              ServicesleftBannerItem[i].style.background = 'white';
               ServicesleftBannerItem[i].style.borderRight = 'none';
              ServicesleftBannerItem[i].style.borderLeft = 'none';
              ServicesleftBannerItem[i].style.borderBottom = 'none';
              ServicesleftBannerItem[i].style.borderTop = '1px solid rgba(115, 115, 115, .3)';
                 }
            ServicesleftBannerItem[ServicesleftBannerItem.length-1].style.borderBottom = '1px solid rgba(115, 115, 115, .3)';

                        for (var i = 0; i < linkArrow.length; i++) 
              {linkArrow[i].style.color = '#000000';
    }               
                                    for (var i = 0; i < ServicesleftBannerItema.length; i++) 
              {ServicesleftBannerItema[i].style.color = '#000000';
    }
             if (ID==1)
     {
            var ServicesleftBannerItemHiddenCheck1 = document.getElementById('ServicesleftBannerItemHiddenCheck1');
             ServicesleftBannerItemHiddenCheck1.style.background = '#737373';
             ServicesleftBannerItemHiddenCheck1.style.border = '1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.5)';
              document.getElementById('ServicesleftBannerItemHiddenCheckA1').style.color = 'white';
              document.getElementById('ServicesleftBannerItemHiddenCheckB1').style.color = 'white';
              document.getElementById("ServicesRight").innerHTML = "About Us";
             }
                     if (ID==2)
     {
            var ServicesleftBannerItemHiddenCheck2 = document.getElementById('ServicesleftBannerItemHiddenCheck2');
             ServicesleftBannerItemHiddenCheck2.style.background = '#737373';
             ServicesleftBannerItemHiddenCheck2.style.border = '1px solid rgba(0,0,0, 0.5)';
              document.getElementById('ServicesleftBannerItemHiddenCheckA2').style.color = 'white';
              document.getElementById('ServicesleftBannerItemHiddenCheckB2').style.color = 'white';
              document.getElementById("ServicesRight").innerHTML = "Privacy Policy";

     }
                }
                  </script>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the referrer in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856697/can-i-get-the-referrer#6856725), i.e. if you want it to do something different when a link on `index` is used.

Comment: Post some code.

Comment: Just add an "onload" on index, and another one on "about_us" ;-) Or.. Provide us a sample as required by Utkanos!

Comment: @Utkanos provided as your request. could you please answer now?

Comment: @Nico Your answer not what I want. thanks. I added some codes.

Comment: There's at least 3 approaches; This kind of thing is usually done server side though which would be a completely different answer to this question. Other two: Use document.referrer, use location.hash. Which is actually suitable depends on a range of things.

Comment: @Nico `window.onload` only works for one function, the last one overrides the previous function calls.

Comment: @Nico I do not think you carefully read my post. every time only one function, but when click different link execute different function.

Comment: @LukeBriggs Thank you. I will research about  document.referrer, use location.hash.

Comment: You change everything in your message, how can I answer you in this conditions? Your original message was, simple, so my answer was.

Comment: @LukeBriggs I solved. Used hash. thank you man.