# Is there a way with javascript to determine if the previous browser history item is in my domain?

Tags: javascript

I have some pages which use the `history.go(-1)` function to return the user to the previous page when the user clicks the close button (a cross in the top right hand corner).

This causes a problem when the user lands directly on a page with this function, as they click "close" expecting to go to a page on my site, but end up going back to whatever external website they just came from.

I don't need (or want) to know their history, just whether or not the place that they came from is a place on my.domain.com or not

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I get the referrer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856697/can-i-get-the-referrer)

Comment: Maybe, although if it's available somehow via the history API I feel that would be a better choice.